# vim make workspace tabs more distinctive

Tags: vim, tabs

When running vim with more than 2 workspaces open in tabs it can be hard to glance and see how many tabs are open and which files they are. The inactive tabs all have the same color and there's no way to see where one ends and the other begins.

Is there any way to put a line between the tabs or alternate their colors?

Comment: Please note that Vim's tab-pages are *not* the same thing as tabs in other editors: they are workspaces, not 1:1 file proxies. You should  get used to Vim's real 1:1 file proxies, buffers.

Comment: +100 @romainl ! multi-files editing without context -> buffers!

Comment: @romainl I don't see how that relates to my problem of distinguishing the tabs.

Comment: @romainl That I use tabs? I understand vim. I'm trying to distinguish the tabs. This has nothing to do with buffers or workspaces, just the tabs visually. Changed the title to say workspace instead of file, that better?

Comment: If you use tab pages as workspaces yes, if you insist on using them as file proxies, no. You don't seem to have noticed but that was a comment on the wrongness of using tab pages as file proxies, not an answer.

Comment: @romainl Then it doesn't belong here. I'm not asking for vim usage advice, just how to make the tabs more visually distinct.

Comment: @romainl at best you're being non-constructive, and worst you're being rude. Please don't waste peoples' time with non-constructive, off-topic comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up making my own vim plugin to do it based on the plugin posted in feihu's answer.

https://github.com/itsgreggreg/tabline.vim

makes the tabs look like so:

`1:foo.txt | 2:bar.html + | 3:bonk.css | 4:baz.js |`

Answer (score 1):

I think show the `tab index` might really help, here is workaround,

[Vim: Show the index of tabs in the tabline](https://superuser.com/questions/331272/vim-show-the-index-of-tabs-in-the-tabline)

[Show tab number in your tab line](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Show_tab_number_in_your_tab_line)

[image: tab number]

And here is the [plugin](https://github.com/mkitt/tabline.vim), (I didn't try because I don't have a MAC, :-P)

Comment: The 1st and 3rd links are for changing the background colors. The 2nd link is relating to the white space 'tab' character. I'm asking about putting a line between the inactive tabs to make them visually distinct. While I do appreciate the help, none of those links address my problem.

Comment: @greggreg, which OS do you use? I checked that tabs on `gvim` looks ok.

Comment: OSX, I'm using vim in the terminal though and not gvim.

Comment: @greggreg, please see the update of the answer for a workaround. this might help.